# How to add keymap (shortcut) in a newly written addon

Tags: python, add-on, keymaps

I am new to the programming and blender. I have written a small addon which is working fine.
But I want to assign that to a key (shortcut).
Can anyone please help me with it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Assign Shortcut link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/389ql.png)

My Addon was made for the Tool section (Press N). Right mouseclick on the button brings up the menu with Assign Shortcut, click that and set your key.

But, there are better forums to ask this